# merge - append the contents of a binary file with a certain order

Tags: linux, perl

in the source directory, i have some binary files named 1.bin, 2.bin, 3.bin, etc. In the dest directory, i have the same named binary files, but with different content. I need to append the contents of the dest directory to the files with the same name, in the source directory, but also be sure that the content of the destination directory will be added below the content of the source directory. This is where i have come:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$source_dir = "/data/source_dir";
$dest_dir   = "/data/dest_dir";
opendir ($source, $source_dir);
@source_files = readdir $source;
foreach $each_file (@source_files){
    if($each !~ /^(\.|\.\.)$/) {
        open $file_h , "< $source_dir/$each_file";
        @contents = <$file_h>;
        open $dest_file, ">>$dest_dir/$each_file";
        print $dest_file @contents;
        @contents =();
     }
}
```

How can i be sure that 1.bin from dest directory is appended - merged under the content of the source directory?

How then the code should look like?

Comment: First order of the day: add `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, fix the errors, then update your question with the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution

- `use autodie` to automatically handle open/close errors
- [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) for path name handling
- read the source file as binary using [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper)
- open the destination file for appending as binary file

  - using the modern 3-argument version of `open()`
  - print the content to the destination file handle

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

use File::Spec;
use File::Slurper qw(read_binary);

my $source_dir = "tmp/source_dir";
my $dest_dir   = "tmp/dest_dir";

opendir(my $source, $source_dir);

foreach my $file (readdir $source) {
    unless ($file =~ /^\.\.?$/) {
        my $content = read_binary(File::Spec->catfile($source_dir, $file));
        open(my $ofh, '>> :raw :bytes', File::Spec->catfile($dest_dir, $file));
        print $ofh $content;
        close($ofh);
    }
}

closedir($source);

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ ls -lhtR tmp/
...
tmp/dest_dir:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 33 22. 3. 20:32 1.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 27 22. 3. 20:32 2.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 15 22. 3. 20:32 3.bin

tmp/source_dir:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 11 22. 3. 20:32 1.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb  9 22. 3. 20:32 2.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb  5 22. 3. 20:31 3.bin

$ perl dummy.pl

$ ls -lhtR tmp/
...
tmp/dest_dir:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 44 22. 3. 20:34 1.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 36 22. 3. 20:34 2.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 20 22. 3. 20:34 3.bin

tmp/source_dir:
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb 11 22. 3. 20:32 1.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb  9 22. 3. 20:32 2.bin
-rw-rw-r--. 1 stefanb stefanb  5 22. 3. 20:31 3.bin
```

---

**UPDATE:** OP changed the requirements to only append if the destination file exists. The `unless` block would then look like:

```perl
my $dest_file = File::Spec->catfile($dest_dir, $file);

# only append if destination file exists
if (-f $dest_file ) {
    my $source_file = File::Spec->catfile($source_dir, $file);
    my $content = read_binary($source_file);
    open(my $ofh, '>> :raw :bytes', $dest_file);
    print "Appending contents of ${source_file} to ${dest_file}\n";
    print $ofh $content;
    close($ofh);
}
```

Comment: How the above could be altered, to add also a report, to have which files had a match, and had content appended, and of those that did not have a match?